Show that there always exists a point $c > 1$ such that $f ( 2 ) - 2 f ( 1 ) = c f ' ( c ) - f ( c )$
Let $f: \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be a differentiable function. Show that there always exists a point $c>1$ such that $f(2)-2f(1)= cf'(c)-f(c)$.
I know that MVT or Rolle's Theorem would be used here. I tried putting $g(x)= xf(x)$, but that did not work because after chain rule, i get an addition sign. So, the I used $g(x)= f(x)/x$, but I am not sure if that is allowed.
I have no idea from where $f(2)$ and $f(1)$ would come. Can anyone give me some idea on how to solve this?

Plugging $ g\left(x\right)=\frac{2}{x}f\left(x\right) $ Will lead you to
$$ g'\left(c\right)=f\left(2\right)-2f\left(1\right) $$
But then differentiating $g$
$$ -\frac{2}{c^{2}}f\left(c\right)+\frac{2}{c}f'\left(c\right)=f\left(2\right)-2f\left(1\right) $$
Which is quite far from what you need

This is https://math.stackexchange.com/q/348882/42969 with $a=1$ and $b=2$.

Apply Lagrange's mean value theorem to $g(x)=x f(1/x)$ in the interval $(1/2,1)$ and the result immediately follows.
Consider a $c' \in (1/2,1)$ then
$$\frac{f(1)-\frac{1}{2} f(2)}{1-\frac{1}{2}}= f(1/c')-\frac{1}{c'} f'(1/c') $$
Since $c' \in (1/2,1)$ let $c=1/c'$ and you are done.
